Laravel no consigue mi controlador
estoy empezando un proyecto desde cero en laravel 6, pero a la hora de llamar mi controlador me dice que no existe, verifique el nombre del controlador y las rutas del mismo pero no he podido solucionarlo, soy nuevo en Laravel apenas estoy aprendiendo.

Has revisado los namespace y los use de la carpeta routes?

Muestra el fichero de rutas para ver exactamente que sucede.
Lo otro es que te recomiendo a esta altura usar laravel 10 como mínimo
